# flutter "fi" character BUG. Can anyone help me fix this

Tags: flutter

Does anyone have this problem in flutter? the f and i character can't be use together in one word.

[image]

F and I is working if they're in capital. Anything else doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the code where this data is converted into UI

Comment: You have probably enabled ligatures but use a font that doesn't include them. Change your font to fix the issue. `fi` and `fii` are common ligatures.